# R: Two y-axes plot using scale_y_continuous(sec.axis) and coord_trans(log10)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to plot a 2y-axes plot; on the left, the actual values, and on the right, the % values. In addition to this, I need to apply coord_trans on the left y-axis for a better visualization of small values. However, when I do it, the labels on the right do not show up.

Here the data ([example](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1outfP0ZCC1D9bYRxhSB-hrpqeRH96cL-?usp=sharing))

Here the code

```
DAXIS <- ggplot(x1, aes(hour, value_T, colour=season, linetype = variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(c("var"), values=c("solid", "dashed", "dotted"))+ # here to change one name
  geom_point(aes(shape = season), size = 1)+
  labs(x = "hour", y = "T") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 6, 12, 18, 23), labels= c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24))+
  scale_y_continuous("T",
                 sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2.341598, name = "     [%] ", 
                                     breaks=c(0.2135294, 0.4270588, 0.6405882, 0.8541176,1),
                                     labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b * 100, 0), "%")}))+
  #coord_trans(y = "log10", breaks=c(0.5,1,1.5,1.903738), labels = c(0.5,1,1.5,1.9))+ # attemp 1
  #coord_trans(y = "log10")+  # attemp 2
  scale_color_aaas()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom", legend.key = element_blank(), 
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "gray30")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
    text=element_text(size=18), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=15))
DAXIS
```

Here the output without coord_trans
[image: without coord_trans]

Here the output with coord_trans
[image: with coord_trans]

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: It looks like the actual values vary by 10-100x, suitable for a log scale, whereas the percentages only increase about 1.5x from the minimum value. You can move the secondary axis down by dividing by a larger number, but it will stay just as narrow unless you manually expand the percentage range using exponents (e.g. by setting = % ^ 10) and then set new secondary breaks (so you label 60% at 0.6 ^ 10 = 0.00605 and 70% at 0.7 ^10 = 0.028, etc.).

Comment: I think using two adjacent charts is cleaner, eg. with facets or using cowplot or patchwork.